# Searching for two strings in program file output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file that will change its output depending upon the output of a command line program.  In order to do so I am trying to search through the output for certain strings that indicate what is happening. The program is to loop continuously until manually closed.

By default, the base program outputs the following:

```
  <Device oid="21" identifier="Silicondust HDHomeRun Tuner 1045D3F7-0 (#0)">
```

When doing an action, the output changes to the following:

```
  <Device oid="21" identifier="Silicondust HDHomeRun Tuner 1045D3F7-0 (#0)">
    <LiveTV handle="15000A">LIVE&amp;D:\Recordings\Buffer\live-Trial-TV-4332-5.ts</LiveTV>
```

The code I am trying to use to detect this change and print an output result is:

```
@echo off
title Tuner Indicator
:begin
Cd "C:\Program Files\NextPVR" 
NScriptHelper.exe -server:127.0.0.1:8866 -status | find /i "identifier=""Silicondust HDHomeRun Tuner 1045D3F7-0 (#0)""" && find /i "</LiveTV"
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo Tuner 1 in use
) 
if %errorlevel% ==1 (        
   echo Tuner 1 not in use
)
goto begin
```

When executed, the command line hangs after printing:

<:Device oid="21" identifier="Silicondust HDHomeRun Tuner 1045D3F7-0 (#0)">

If I delete either one of the strings, it executes correctly. However, I need to find both strings for my usage. If I change the && to | the script always prints "Tuner 1 not in use".

I just can not figure out why it won't work & where the error(s) may be.  My guess would be with the quotation escape sequence placement. Any help/guidance on how to get this working is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Cd "C:\Program Files\NextPVR" 
set "found1="&set "found2="
for /f "delims="%%b in ('NScriptHelper.exe -server:127.0.0.1:8866 -status') do (
 echo "%%b"| find /i "identifier=""Silicondust HDHomeRun Tuner 1045D3F7-0 (#0)""">nul
 if not errorlevel 1 set "found1=Y"
 echo "%%b"|find /i "</LiveTV">nul
 if not errorlevel 1 set "found2=Y"
)
if "%found1%%found2%"=="YY" echo Tuner in use
if "%found1%%found2%"=="Y" echo Tuner not in use
if "%found1%%found2%"=="" echo Tuner not found
```

In your code, the `find` of the first string outputs only that line that passes the test.

If you follow that with `&` or `&&` then it will show that line and then execute the second `find` as an independent command. Since that second `find` has no input, and no file specified for it to read, it waits for input from the keyboard, hence appearing to stop.

OTOH, If you follow it with `|` then the output of the first `find`  (just that line that passes the first `find`'s test) is piped to the second `find` where it will fail the test, show no output and set `errorlevel` to `1` (not found).

My posted code:

First set `foundx` to *nothing*, then rin the executable, assigning the whole of each line of output to `%%b`. `echo` that line to each of the `find`s in turn, discarding the output and if the `find` finds a match, set `errorlevel` to `0`.

The `if not errorlevel 1` tests for `errorlevel=0`. `Set` the appropriate `found`

Whean each line of the executable's output has been processed, analyse the settings of `foundx`.

Comment: I apologize for such a late response. Thank You for your reply.

That explanation makes sense as to why would work independently but not together.  Running the check twice & storing as variables was actually going to be my next idea but figured I was just overcomplicating it.